# Python. How to find and group duplicated value in dictionry of list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I need to find any intersection in lists and group them in a new list.

I have a dictionary for example:

```
my_dict = {A:[1, 5], B:[1, 3], C:[0, 5], D:[4, 7], E:[9, 8]}
```

```
new_list = [A, B, C]
or the dict
new_dict = [A:[1, 5], B:[1, 3], C:[0, 5]]

explanation of this A B and C have intersected value in 1 and 5.
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: I am confused on the criteria to exclude D, D's values are not in any of the other elements?

Comment: that's the case, Yes the D is not intersect of any others

Comment: [edit] the question, don’t put code in comments.

Comment: What should be the result if the input is `{A: [1, 2], B: [2, 3], C: [4, 5], D: [5, 6]}`?

Comment: no, the input have {A:[1, 5], B:[1, 3], C:[0, 5], D:[4, 7]}, an intersected value in 1, and 5 in this case, and output should have A B and C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can list all possible intersections:

```
my_dict = {'A':[1, 5], 'B':[1, 3], 'C':[0, 5], 'D':[4, 7]}
new_list = []

for k in my_dict:
    c = [k]
    for l in my_dict:
        if k!=l:
            if any(a==b for a in my_dict[k] for b in my_dict[l]):
                c.append(l)
    if len(c) > 1:
        new_list.append(c)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'A'], ['C', 'A']]
```